# Angular Async Pipe

Tags: angular, telerik

I have the below configuration. The onInit calls the service, and the service populates the grid via the 'async | pipe'. My question is, on the component, how can I further manipulate the data that comes back? I want my service to grab the data, and my **component** to also catch the response and manipulate it the way it specifically needs it, and update the view?

**component.ts**

```
public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
constructor(private serviceTest: IfpServiceTest)
{
    this.view = serviceTest;
}
public ngOnInit(): void
{
    this.serviceTest.queryForIFP(``, this.state);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="view | async"> </kendo-grid>
```

**ifp.service.ts**

```
return this.http
      .get(`${this.BASE_URL}${tableName}?${queryString}`)
      .pipe(
        map((response: Response) => (<GridDataResult>{
          data: response.data,
          total: response.count// parseInt(response.length, 10)
        })),
        tap(() => this.loading = false)
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use subscribe and modify the data as per your need

**TS**

```
public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
constructor(private serviceTest: IfpServiceTest)
{
    this.view = serviceTest;
}
public ngOnInit(): void
{
    this.serviceTest.queryForIFP(``, this.state).subscribe(resp => {
       console.log(resp); // here you can do further operations 
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- In html we are not useing async pipe bcs we already use subscribe in TS -->
<kendo-grid [data]="view"> </kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as you used pipeable operators (map, tap, etc) to manipulate the data in ifp.service.ts, you can do same in the component to further manipulate the data. 
This'll allow you to for instance store the returned data in a component level variable, or call a function in the component to manipulate the data and return the result, giving you the advantage of still handling you subscription with the async pipe.

```js
public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
constructor(private serviceTest: IfpServiceTest) {
  this.view = serviceTest;
  response;
}
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.serviceTest.queryForIFP(``, this.state)
      .pipe(
          map(response => {
            this.response = response;
            return this.doSomethingWithResponse(response);
          })
      );
}

doSomethingWithResponse(response) {
  return response;
}
```

And in your view as before you use the async pipe to subscribe:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="view | async"> </kendo-grid>
```